# Do "free" ArcGIS Online service credits expire or accumulate?

Tags: arcgis-online

Do the "free" ArcGIS Online service credits expire or accumulate? For example, if my license comes with 100 credits, and I have used 50 at time of renewal, will after renewal I have 150 or 100?

I know that additionally-purchased credits are good for 24 months. Unclear as to the life of the "free" credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no mention of rollover of service credits in the description of the free ones you get, then I would expect them to expire, which matches my experience from the past few years.

As [commented by @RussRoberts](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/266046/do-free-arcgis-online-service-credits-expire-or-accumulate#comment422673_266047):

> The ‘Free’ credits are the annual credits that come with a
>   subscription every year. These expire and renew with the subscription.
>   Additionally purchased credits are available for 24 months. ‘Free’
>   subscription credits are consumed first, leaving the purchased credits
>   to roll over when not consumed within the year. There is no way to
>   manage how you spend which credits. If there are questions about this,
>   suggest moving the conversation to Geonet or getting in contact with
>   their account manager.

Comment: Thank you. This then begs another question: If I have both "free" and purchased credits, good for 12 and 24 months respectively, which credits get consumed first?

Comment: If the documentation that comes with your license does not explain it then that, like this question, is really one that you should be asking Esri. The fair model would be to consume the free ones first.

Comment: The ‘Free’ credits are the annual credits that come with a subscription every year. These expire and renew with the subscription. Additionally purchased credits are available for 24 months. ‘Free’ subscription credits are consumed first, leaving the purchased credits to roll over when not consumed within the year. There is no way to manage how you spend which credits. If there are questions about this, suggest moving the conversation to Geonet or getting in contact with their account manager.